# Почему не воспроизводится плейлист?

Tags: xml, аудио

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чём ошибка:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<playlist version="1">  
<trackList>  
<track>  
<location>media/com_podcastmanager/Literatura/Maershin/Crysis/Crysis_01.mp3</location>  
<title>1 часть</title>  
<creator>Андрей Маершин</creator>  
<album>Кризис среднего возраста</album>  
<info>twrradio.ru</info>  
</track>    

<track>  
<location>media/com_podcastmanager/Literatura/Maershin/Crysis/Crysis_02.mp3</location>  
<title>2 часть</title>  
<creator>Андрей Маершин</creator>  
<album>Кризис среднего возраста</album>  
<info>twrradio.ru</info>  
</track>  
</trackList>
</playlist>
```

Плейлист отображается, но не воспроизводится. Ссылки указаны правильно - при переходе по ним всё открывается. Работаю с плагином JosDewPlayer. 
Заранее гигантское спасибо.

Comment: Это не программирование. А у вас указана кодировка utf-8. Соответствует?

Comment: Разобралась. Перед ссылками на записи нужны слеши. =_=
___

С кодировкой всё ок.)